# How to recover lost partition after diskutil erasevolume?

Tags: disk-utility, partition, mojave

I have the same problem as [How to recover lost partition after diskutil erasevolume noformat](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/250776/how-to-recover-lost-partition-after-diskutil-erasevolume-noformat)

The op in that post solved by going into Internet Recovery. I did that but problem remains. Reinstall of MacOS didn't work either.

Here's my output for relevant commands:

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         96.2 GB    disk0s2
   3:         Microsoft Reserved                         16.8 MB    disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +96.2 GB    disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            74.5 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 43.7 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                517.1 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4

$ diskutil cs list
No CoreStorage logical volume groups found

$ sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  187824088      2  GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  188233728      32768      3  GPT part - E3C9E316-0B5C-4DB8-817D-F92DF00215AE
  188266496   48711647         
  236978143         32         Sec GPT table
  236978175          1         Sec GPT header

$ sudo fdisk /dev/disk0
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 14751/255/63 [236978176 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -  236978175] <Unknown ID>
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

I think there's about 20-24gb in that lost partition

additional info:
- macOS Mojave v10.14.2
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)

I'd really like to recover it and join into my main partition (I think is disk0s2)

Comment: Your question is slightly different from [Restore main APFS container to full disk](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346993/restore-main-apfs-container-to-full-disk), but the answer is exactly the same.

Comment: @DavidAnderson, Hi, thank you very much for replying. I'll be trying that once I get home, but based on the answer on that post, my disk0s3 is "Microsoft Reserved" and only 16.8 MB, will erasing this one fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not recover the free space because the small 16 MB "Microsoft Reserved" partition is between the APFS container and this free space. The command below will remove the "Microsoft Reserved" partition and add the 16 MB to the 24.9 GB of free space that already exists.

```
diskutil eraseVolume free none disk0s3
```

The next command will expand the APFS container to occupy the free space.

```
diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```